# SQL Server - Shuffle results randomly, but with a weight assigned to each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I know that the normal way to shuffle results with SQL Server is to order by `NEWID()`, except I'd like to instead use a weighted shuffle.

Each record in my table has an integer 'Importance' from 1 to 10. I'd like to order by `RAND()*Importance`, except SQL Server has `RAND()` return the same value for each record returned.

Any ideas please?

Comment: do you mean order by weight, random, or just some kind of "loaded dices" where record with 10 will be probably before record with 1?

Comment: Loaded dices. If I have two records, with Importance values of 1 and 10, I'd expect to see the one with 10 to appear first around 9 out of 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL Server - Set based random numbers](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-set-based-random-numbers) for some ideas

Comment: Thanks. ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 100 * Importance did the job perfectly.